# Making 2 different types of links tappable in a TextView

Tags: android, textview

There are two types of links I need to make tappable in a `TextView`.

---

The first type is the address typed as text.

Example:

`http://www.google.com`

---

The second type is an HTML hyperlink.

Example:

`<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>`

Which would then show up as:

`Google`

---

I can accomplish type 2 by setting the `TextView's` movement method and using the `HTML` object.

Example:

```
holder.txtMyText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
holder.txtMyText.setText(Html.fromHtml(items.get(position).getText()));
```

---

I can accomplish type 1 by setting the `TextView's` `autoLink` parameter to "web."

Example:

`android:autoLink="web"`

---

The problem:

If I set the `TextView's` `autoLink` parameter to "web," it breaks the HTML hyperlinks.  They show up as normal text and are not tappable.  If I remove the `autoLink` parameter, typed addresses are no longer tappable.

How do I make both work?

Comment: You could try manually running `Linkify` against the output of `Html.fromHtml()`. Or, wrap the bare URLs in `<a>` tags for the purposes of displaying them.

Comment: this is because Linkify.addLinks() removes every URLSpan that is already in Spannable object (see http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/util/Linkify.java#204)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using following regular expression worked:

```
// Match any set of characters starting with `http` but not in `<a></a>` tag
static final String REGEX = "(?!<a[^>]*?>)(http[^\\s]+)(?![^<]*?</a>)";
```

**Example:**

*string:*

```
<string name="lorem_ipsum">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a> eirmod tempor.
    \n\n\n\n\n\n
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum http://www.google.com clita kasd sed.
</string>
```

*layout:*

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lorem_ipsum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />
```

*activity:*

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lorem_ipsum);
Linkify.addLinks(tv, Pattern.compile(REGEX), "http://");
```

**Result:**

[image: Screenshot]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!  This works, though it should be mentioned that `tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())` is required for the link with `<a></a>` tags to be clickable.

Answer (score 2):

`autoLink` is defined as a flag, you can combine multiple values using the bitwise OR operator `|`

=> `android:autoLink="web|email"`